# Finding widest horizontal line in contour

Tags: python, opencv, contour

After I've extracted the coontours of of the objects via findContours(), I´d like to find the widest horizontal line through each of the contours. I have already tried to use the extreme points but as the shapes defere, it doesn´t result in horizontal lines...
code so far:

```
###contour extraction
cnts = cv2.findContours(img_thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnts = cnts[0]
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts)

for cnt in cnts:
    if cv2. contourArea(cnt) > 500:
        contour_lenght = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.009 * contour_lenght, True)
        obj_cor = len(approx)

        if obj_cor > 4:
            cv2.drawContours(blank_image, cnt, -1, (0, 0, 0), 1)
###boundingbox
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        bbox = (x, y), (x, y + h), (x + w, y + h), (x + w, y)
        tl = (x, y)
        bl = (x, y + h)
        br = (x + w, y + h)
        tr = (x + w, y)

        bbox = cv2.rectangle(blank_image_3, (tl), (br), (0, 0, 0), 1)
        cnt_poly = cv2.polylines(blank_image_3, cnt, True, (0, 0, 0))

###extreme points
        leftmost = tuple(approx[approx[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        rightmost = tuple(approx[approx[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])

        cv2.circle(blank_image_3, leftmost, 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
        cv2.circle(blank_image_3, rightmost, 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

        leftmost = (leftmost[0], leftmost[1])
        leftmost_direction = (leftmost[0] + w, leftmost[1])
        rightmost_direction = (rightmost[0] - w, rightmost[1])
```

[image shows the outlines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07gfc.png)
[outlines with bbox and extreme points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo8QL.png)

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Please show your input image without the red lines at full resolution and also your code.  Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you draw each contour onto a new image so that the background is black and the inside of the contour is white, then you can take the integral going left to right (i.e. the sum of each row). The row with the maximum sum will have the most white pixels in it, i.e. the thickest part of the contour.